# highcharts JSON google earth

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts, google-earth

I would like to show a pie chart (using Highcharts library) inside a placemark's popup box (google earth desktop) from data taken from a mysql database residing on a live server.

The chart is intended to be dynamic and realtime.

From my research I found that I can do it using JSON formatted data taken from a php script in the server and sent to the HTML file pre-processed.

I put the html code (highcharts.html) inside the placemark popup and it refers to the retrieve_data.php file residing in the server .

The php file is fetching successfully the dummy data (if you access the address of the php script referenced inside the html code you can see them) so it seems that the JSON encoding is done.

The thing now is how to finally send them at the Google earth placemark (or the Google earth placemark to fetch them)....

Am I missing something in the communication with the server or I do something wrong??

note: this is my first contact with JSON data transfer!

Below are the files that i use.

Thank you all in advance for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'gjcgjcgjcgjj'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: []
                }]
            }

<!-- maybe the correct file address is http://diss.web44.net/retrieve_data.php -->
                $.getJSON("http://diss.web44.net/home/a1964573/public_html/retrieve_data.php", function(json) {
                options.series[0].data = json;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });



        });   
        </script>


        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

------------and the php file---------

```
<?php

$hostname = "host";
$username = "user";
$pass     = "pass";
$db       = "awesomedb";

$connection = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$pass);

if (!$connection) 
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT sensorID,temp FROM ccdata");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row[0] = $r[0];
    $row[1] = $r[1];
    array_push($rows,$row);
}

print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this URL is proper one (at least for me): http://diss.web44.net/retrieve_data.php

And your JSON has all numbers as strings, for example: `["Direct Sales","20.00"]` -> 20.00 is a string, while should be nuber. Change that to get numbers and will work fine.

Comment: Hello Pawel, thank you for your answer.it was right on spot. I managed to make it work by installing PHP version 5.3.3 and above.Yet when I transfer the same code inside a google earth placemark ballon it does not show anything. is it something else that i must do?

Comment: In that link: http://diss.web44.net/retrieve_data.php I still can see strings instaed of numbers. Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: I have abandoned this url to be honest. I now host them in my server. What i describe above most probably has to do with GoogleEarth. Outside of GE works perfectly. Inside the graph can be shown only when there is a link that points to the highcharts html file.And it shows the graph inside GE like a browser.

Comment: Huh, I haven't tried use HC with GE. Are you including jQuery? Also, are you triggering chart creating after DOM(?) is fully loaded? Is there anything printed? Like title, legend etc? If not, are there any errors, or more important, is SVG supported in GE?

Comment: Yes jQuery is included along with the HC js files. HC is creating the chart after the "document" is ready.                                                                    For sure GE can render SVG because if I put the HTML inside the placemark's balloon description but the data are hardcoded,the chart is spotless. When I try to fetch them remotely nothing appears...

Comment: So hardcoded chart is rendered fine? But using AJAX isn't? Well, could you dump once again what is returned from JSON? For example in success function: `var str = JSON.stringify(data); $("#container").text(str);` - instead of creating chart, dump to container data in string format, there may be some culprits. Result should be like this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7cKP/

Comment: Yes the hardcoded data are rendered fine but when I try to get data from the "outside" then the balloon is blank. Could it be prohibited to run a script that points outside of GE for security reasons?I created a placemark with the fiddle's code and the balloon just shows the JS code (the function). You can see the data I get from the server here http://83.212.10.102/charts/sensor0.php . As i understand they are in the same format as the fiddle.